# How can I restrict a user to a specific item in the Wordpress Admin?

Tags: wp-admin, permissions

Let us assume I want to restrict someone only to accessing the comments section of the WP-Admin interface.

I don't think that this functionality is covered by the default group permissions.

How could I limit a user to only a specific section of the WP-Admin interface?

[image]

Comment: As you ask it right now, this is just to broad, please edit your question and add all the specific details relevant here

Comment: I agree with @MarkKaplun. Downloads, for instance, is a non-standard WordPress menu item. How could we advise you on removing it if we don't know how it ended up there in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Better now?

Comment: Is changing the users or roles [capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) an option? I think that would be the safest and cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Yes Luis, that would be fully satisfactory!